# HDMI cable not able to trigger monitor turning off

Tags: display, hdmi

I have 2 HDMI cables. Connecting the same monitor (DELL U2515H) and the same computer.
They both works in term of displaying. But they appeares to be differnet about making monitor off.

Cable 1:
When computer turned off, or go sleep, the monitor immediate turned off automaticly.

Cable 2:
When computer turned off, or go sleep, the monitor shows a message: No signal and will off in 5 minutes.

All other settings are the same, only the difference is the cable.

Any idea why?

Comment: Different versions perhaps?